# GridSearchCV not working with Pipeline's memory parameter and concurrency (n_jobs > 1)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using a pipeline as an estimator for the `GridSearchCV`. Which works fine. However, if I enable caching with the memory paramater and set `n_jobs` to larger than one, `cv_results_`'s score columns are `NaN` and it is done in like a second instead of several minutes.

Do you cannot use the caching functionality with `GridSearchCV` or what am I doing wrong?

```py
gsCV = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=Pipeline(
#         memory='../Cache/AW1MP_N10_DIN276_Pipeline', # not working if enabled
        steps=[
            ('we', FastTextTransformer()), 
            ('se', AverageWordVectorTransformer()),
            ('rf', RandomForestClassifier())
        ]

    ),
    param_grid=[
        {
            'we__min_count': [5],
            'we__size': [64],
            'we__window': [5],
            'we__min_n': [3],
            'we__max_n': [6],
            'rf__n_estimators': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10],# 25, 64, 128], # number of trees in forest
            'rf__criterion':['gini'],#'entropy'], # split criterion
            'rf__max_features':['auto'], # number of features per tree,
            'rf__max_depth':[4, 8, 16]#, 32, 64, 128]
        }
    ], 
    cv=CV,
    verbose=VERBOSE,
    n_jobs=N_JOBS,
    return_train_score=True,
    scoring=None
)

gsCV.fit(X_train, label_encoder.inverse_transform(Y_train).reshape(-1))
```

#### Output without the memory parameter

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 6 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done   1 tasks      | elapsed:   28.9s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done   6 tasks      | elapsed:   29.4s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done  13 tasks      | elapsed:  1.5min
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done  20 tasks      | elapsed:  2.0min
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done  29 tasks      | elapsed:  2.5min
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done  38 tasks      | elapsed:  3.5min
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done  49 tasks      | elapsed:  4.5min
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done  60 tasks      | elapsed:  5.1min
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done  73 tasks      | elapsed:  6.6min
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done  90 out of  90 | elapsed:  7.6min finished
```

#### Output with the memory parameter set to a path

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 6 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done   1 tasks      | elapsed:    3.3s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done   6 tasks      | elapsed:    3.3s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done  13 tasks      | elapsed:    3.7s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done  20 tasks      | elapsed:    4.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done  29 tasks      | elapsed:    4.3s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done  38 tasks      | elapsed:    4.7s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done  49 tasks      | elapsed:    5.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done  60 tasks      | elapsed:    5.4s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done  73 tasks      | elapsed:    5.9s
[Parallel(n_jobs=6)]: Done  90 out of  90 | elapsed:    6.4s finished
C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\SDaC\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py:296: UserWarning: Persisting input arguments took 1.40s to run.
If this happens often in your code, it can cause performance problems 
(results will be correct in all cases). 
The reason for this is probably some large input arguments for a wrapped
 function (e.g. large strings).
THIS IS A JOBLIB ISSUE. If you can, kindly provide the joblib's team with an
 example so that they can fix the problem.
  **fit_params_steps[name])

C:\Users\username\anaconda3\envs\SDaC\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py:296: UserWarning: Persisting input arguments took 5.32s to run.
If this happens often in your code, it can cause performance problems 
(results will be correct in all cases). 
The reason for this is probably some large input arguments for a wrapped
 function (e.g. large strings).
THIS IS A JOBLIB ISSUE. If you can, kindly provide the joblib's team with an
 example so that they can fix the problem.
  **fit_params_steps[name])
```

#### Output with `error_score='raise'`

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-247-f1d887547f42> in <module>
     19 )
     20 
---> 21 gsCV_clf.fit(X_train, label_encoder.inverse_transform(Y_train).reshape(-1)) # use class because of Random Forest Classifier
     22 print('hi')

~\anaconda3\envs\SDaC\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

~\anaconda3\envs\SDaC\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    734                 return results
    735 
--> 736             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    737 
    738         # For multi-metric evaluation, store the best_index_, best_params_ and

~\anaconda3\envs\SDaC\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1186     def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1187         """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1188         evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
   1189 
   1190 

~\anaconda3\envs\SDaC\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params)
    713                                for parameters, (train, test)
    714                                in product(candidate_params,
--> 715                                           cv.split(X, y, groups)))
    716 
    717                 if len(out) < 1:

~\anaconda3\envs\SDaC\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1052 
   1053             with self._backend.retrieval_context():
-> 1054                 self.retrieve()
   1055             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
   1056             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

~\anaconda3\envs\SDaC\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in retrieve(self)
    931             try:
    932                 if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
--> 933                     self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
    934                 else:
    935                     self._output.extend(job.get())

~\anaconda3\envs\SDaC\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in wrap_future_result(future, timeout)
    540         AsyncResults.get from multiprocessing."""
    541         try:
--> 542             return future.result(timeout=timeout)
    543         except CfTimeoutError as e:
    544             raise TimeoutError from e

~\anaconda3\envs\SDaC\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    433                 raise CancelledError()
    434             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 435                 return self.__get_result()
    436             else:
    437                 raise TimeoutError()

~\anaconda3\envs\SDaC\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in __get_result(self)
    382     def __get_result(self):
    383         if self._exception:
--> 384             raise self._exception
    385         else:
    386             return self._result

PicklingError: ("Can't pickle <class '__main__.CustomTokenizer'>: it's not found as __main__.CustomTokenizer", 'PicklingError while hashing {\'transformer\': CustomTokenizer(), \'X\':       kostenposition_bau_nr_komplett  ...                                               text\n12862                            326  ...                           Fenster Holzfenster AQ 1\n17556                            326  ...       Scheiben verkratzt Holzfenster AQ 7, 8.1-8.2\n11648                            314  ...  Boden am Übergang zwischen Naturstein und Beto...\n2344                             300  ...  Farbverschmutzung Decke (Lampe) Farbverschmutz...\n13097                            326  ...  Sonnenschutz einstellen linkes Fenster klapper...\n...                              ...  ...                                                ...\n17213                            327  ...  105 Küche Fuge Arbeitsplatte Rückwand fehlt Ti...\n4200                             300  ...  offene Hartverfugung Boden (Dusche) offene Har...\n12443                            327  ...   Leichter Versatzder verkleidungsteile am Lich...\n14023                            324  ...        Fuge mit Lücken Bad GU AQ 4, 5, 6, 8.1, 8.2\n3635                             300  ...  reinigen Glashalteleiste (WC) reinigen Glashal...\n\n[9731 rows x 3 columns], \'y\': array([\'326\', \'326\', \'314\', ..., \'327\', \'324\', \'300\'], dtype=\'<U3\'), \'weight\': None, \'message_clsname\': \'Pipeline\', \'message\': None, \'**\': {}}: PicklingError("Can\'t pickle <class \'__main__.CustomTokenizer\'>: it\'s not found as __main__.CustomTokenizer")')
```

#### Additional Information

- scikit-learn 0.23.2

Comment: Any errors or warnings produced?  Does the cache file get populated?

Comment: I appended the warnings to the questions. Though it seemed like they were only performance warnings. I got about 1 GB in the caching folder `_fit_transform_one`

Comment: Do you get the same issue with `n_jobs=1`?

Comment: It works fine with `n_jobs=1`. There are also more folder created under `joblib/sklearn/pipeline/_fit_transform_one` with `n_jobs=1`, about 15+ or so. With `n_jobs>1` there are only 3 folder created.

Comment: Try setting `error_score='raise'` in the grid search; there is probably an error getting hidden from us by the search.  Then you can provide that error and we may be able to resolve it.

Comment: That was very useful. It seems my own transformer class cannot be pickled. I added the error message to the question.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/45335524/10495893 then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom sklearn pipeline transformer giving "pickle.PicklingError"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45335524/custom-sklearn-pipeline-transformer-giving-pickle-picklingerror)

Answer (score -1):

I tried to deal with the referred problem calling Tensorflow just inside the model definition, which I believe is the instance called inside GridSearchCV in the parallel execution. You can find my model definition below. clear_session() is supposed to free the memory of every graph in the sessions created during parallel grid search execution. config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True and config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.3 provides a way of using GridSearchCV with n_jobs=-1 (n_jobs >1). After these modifications in my code, I can see multiple training streams and no apparent accumulative memory usage increase. Note that the fraction should be enough each process can be executed. If there are many concurrent process the fraction can't avoid memory explosion. One solution is defining fraction as 1/(number cpus). But there is a risk of the fraction being not enough to the process to be executed if there are many cpus. Besides, when more than 1 GPU is available, the total amount of memory of the GPU with low memory must be observed.

```
# Function to create model, required for KerasClassifier
def mlp(
loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', 
metrics=['accuracy'], init_mode='uniform',
activation='relu', dropout_rate=0.0, weight_constraint=2,
neurons=12, input_shape = (5,)
):
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential # type: ignore
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense # type: ignore
from tensorflow.keras.constraints import MaxNorm # type: ignore
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout # type: ignore

# This is to try to cope with memory leak caused by graph creation
# in Tensorflow.
from tensorflow.keras.backend import clear_session # type: ignore
clear_session()

# This is supposed to help with OOM problem when using multiprocess
# and gridsearch. Including the memory limit.
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto # type: ignore
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.backend import set_session # type: ignore
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import Session # type: ignore
config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.3
set_session(Session(config=config)) # type: ignore

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(
    units=neurons, input_shape=input_shape, kernel_initializer=init_mode, 
    activation=activation, kernel_constraint=MaxNorm(weight_constraint))
)
model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer=init_mode, activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=metrics)
return model
```

Comment: Did you post this in the wrong place?  It doesn't seem related to this question at all...